# Problems with mysql create procedure from doctrine raw sql

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, procedure

I am working with an application project in Symfony2.
By registration, per client, a database is created.
Schemas are created by a validation service when the client logs on.
The application needs some data to work, and so far, I used ORM fixtures.
For a number of reasons, I now need to move from fixtures load to get more close to the database.
I have created a stored procedure (mysql) which will replace all data loading. The procedure works, but I need to create this procedure in each database together with the schema.
I use doctrine raw sql for this purpose but I cannot get pass a problem with the first lines of the create procedure statement. It seems it's got to do with the 'delimiter $$'.

While executing the service with the sql statement i get: 
"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'delimiter $$\r\n\r\nCREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost"

It seems to be because of line-breaks but I am not sure. Anyone knows of some way around this?

Comment: How about just using a different delimiter?  Obviously $ is a special character for php.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried:
DELIMITER // CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_register`(IN user_id INT) DETERMINISTIC COMMENT 'Registration procedure' BEGIN INSERT INTO metatitle(column1) SELECT 'example' as column1; END // DELIMITER ;
From mysql work bench which works fine as long as I include a break line after the DELIMITER //
If I do it in a single row I get no response.

Comment: Did you try double quotes around the string and using the "\n" character for newlines when you need them?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but did not get it to work. I will try an alternative solution and build a service-layer with a library of raw sql in Symfony. My intention is to call the service with a parameter and use replace on the raw-sql string to make it work like a stored procedure. This way I can control it better from the application without loosing functionality. Thank you for your help. If you come up with another solution I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 9):

The problem comes from the fact that delimiter command can only be used when using the MySQL Command-Line Tool as discussed http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html.  To fix this problem you need to remove the part where you are changing the delimiter and just use ; as your delimiter.  Consider the following:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
   SET @x = 0;
   REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END$$
```

The above will not work however the following will:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    SET @x = 0;
    REPEAT SET @x = @x + 1; UNTIL @x > p1 END REPEAT;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perhaps override the CREATE DEFINER, since in the system where you will be launching your procedure the root@localhost is not a mysql or database user.

Comment: Yes you may be right. But so far, my problem is with creating the procedure from doctrine raw sql. I will be glad to follow up on this if I get pass the current issue

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer however this post is high in Google's results and I found no other answer elsewhere so I would like to post a solution how to overcome the issue.

Long story short, one has to break the lines with the \n character inside the query, for instance:

```
$this->addSql(
    "CREATE EVENT event_example ON SCHEDULE EVERY 15 MINUTE ".
    "ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN\n".
    "INSERT INTO archives SELECT * FROM records;\n".
    "DELETE FROM records;\n".
    "END"
);
```