# Symfony (with doctrine) migration not working with a valid mysql function creation request

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

When I return the following MySQL migration with the symfony command `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

```php
<?php                                                                                                 
                                                   
declare(strict_types=1);        
                                                   
namespace DoctrineMigrations;
                                                   
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;                                                                      
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;                                                            
                                                   
/**                         
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */                                                                                                   
final class Version20211112124807 extends AbstractMigration
{                                             
    public function getDescription() : string
    {                                     
        return '';                
    }                     
                                                   
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {         
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS wordcount;");
        $this->addSql("
            DELIMITER $$
            CREATE FUNCTION wordcount(str LONGTEXT)
                   RETURNS INT
                   DETERMINISTIC
                   SQL SECURITY INVOKER
                   NO SQL
              BEGIN
                DECLARE wordCnt, idx, maxIdx INT DEFAULT 0;
                DECLARE currChar, prevChar BOOL DEFAULT 0;
                SET maxIdx=char_length(str);
                SET idx = 1;
                WHILE idx <= maxIdx DO
                    SET currChar=SUBSTRING(str, idx, 1) RLIKE '[[:alnum:]]';
                    IF NOT prevChar AND currChar THEN
                        SET wordCnt=wordCnt+1;
                    END IF;
                    SET prevChar=currChar;
                    SET idx=idx+1;
                END WHILE;
                RETURN wordCnt;
              END
            $$
            DELIMITER ;
        ");

        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article ADD words_amount INT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL');

        $this->addSql("UPDATE article SET article.words_amount = wordcount( article.content )");
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->addSql('ALTER TABLE article DROP words_amount');
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$  CREATE FUNCTION wordcount(str LONGTEXT)
```

But when I paste the `wordcount` function declaration directly into my mysql console, everything is ok (I have checked with `show function status`).

Do you know or have you an idea why it is not working?
Or maybe there is another way which I do not know.

For your information, I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259528/2600812 ??

Comment: So if I understand it well, I just cannot use this migration because doctrine does not support delimiters. Thank you for your help, by understanding better my issue, I have search internet with different keywords, and found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19340046/problems-with-mysql-create-procedure-from-doctrine-raw-sql so if can define a function in the doctrine migration and I must not use the delimiters.